# Why has an attempt to account for seasonality in my data made my machine learning results ridiculous?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, python, seasonality

I am trying to use machine learning (using linear regression) to predict bandwidth use into the future. I have over 50,000 observations spread across 56 weeks (just over a years data), and I am currently using time (limited to the one year) and number of users (which is growing over time) as X values to predict the Y (bandwidth use).

The predictions I received were relatively sensible, except that when I fed X values to predict a Y, and when I would increase the time values, predicted bandwidth would fall slightly (going against intuition and past granular data of my company). I thought this could be due to a seasonal effect (internet use falls in the summer as people go outside and rises again in the winter) so I added binary variables for seasons to my data to account for this (i.e. winter = 1 during December, January, February, spring = 1 during March etc). However once I incorporated these, my predictions became ridiculous; multiplying in various directions by factors of millions from what they should be (e.g. from 12Tb/s to -300000000Tb/s, or -900000000Tb/s).

Without seasonality coefficients are:
Customers: 0.97
Time: 0.043
With seasonality coefficients are:
Customers: 9.7e-01
Time: 6.5e-02
Season binaries: all between -6.3e+10 to -7.3e+10

So I am asking, what could be causing this unintuitive result - why is the model somehow massively overestimating the effect of seasonality? Is the way I tried to incorporate seasonality wrong? am I using the wrong model (linear regression) and thus should I remove my seasonal binaries and change the model? Or is it some other issue?

Also if it is impossible to account for seasonal effects with my data, is there some other way to get the time X variable to behave as expected? (Time is accounted for by incrementing each next week of data by a value of 1)

Thank you in advance for any help

EDIT: SOLVED - Issue was the dummy variable trap. Removing one of the seasonal binaries when feeding data fixed the issue

Comment: How exactly is your time variable defined?

Comment: @E.Sommer Time is accounted for by incrementing each week by a value of 1. (First week of data is 1, second week is 2 etc). All the data is then standardised before feeding into the model

Comment: And if you predict beyond your observed sample, do you increment the time variable to 57, 58, 59, ...? Did you check whether your seasonality variable is correctly specified for future periods?

Comment: @E.Sommer That's right, for instance I would enter 108 if I want to predict a year in advance. Although to test if my model is sensible I have used values under 56 and compared to the existing data. The answers are in the right ballpark without season binaries, but once they are included they become nonsensical, regardless of the time variable entered

Comment: Likely reason is that seasonality is mis-specified. Check in the data...e.g. is only one of winter/spring/summer/fall equal to 1? Could you post the coefficients for your model with and without seasonality?

Comment: If you look at the regression coefficients after adding seasonality, some of them must be very large. Which ones? Have you got an intercept in addition to the four seasons?

Comment: @E.Sommer I have just double checked the data and all the rows have only one of the binaries set as a '1'. Without seasonality coefficients are - Customers: 0.97 || Time: 0.043. With seasonality coefficients are - Customers: 9.7e-01 || Time: 6.5e-02 || the season binaries are all between -6.3e+10 to -7.3e+10. Clearly there is a massive overemphasis on them

Comment: @AccidentalStatistician Without seasonality coefficients are - Customers: 0.97 || Time: 0.043. With seasonality coefficients are - Customers: 9.7e-01 || Time: 6.5e-02 || the season binaries are all between -6.3e+10 to -7.3e+10. I'm not sure, I am using sklearn's linear regression and I have not explicitly coded anything in regards to a coefficient, could it be an issue of dummy variable trap?

Comment: Do you leave out one of the seasonality indicators? You always need to omit one.

Comment: @E.Sommer Yeah I did not do that. That fixed it, can't believe I managed to forget the dummy variable trap, thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Can you please then answer your own question, so that it not lingers on as unsolved.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen added the answer now, apologies, I'm new to the site

Comment: Good that this was resolved. Some software automatically checks for this so that there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Issue was the dummy variable trap. Removing one of the seasonal binaries when feeding data fixed the issue